# Django Modelviewset try to create custom route

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

```
@action(detail=False, methods=['GET'], name='Get Vesting Locaitons')
def get_vesting_locations(self, request, pk=None, *args, **kwargs):
```

I'm trying to return json response and get 404 error

this is the  the route regiser

```
router.register(r'vesting', VestingViewSet, basename='vesting')
```

and those are the urls im trying to get

```
http://localhost:8000/vesting/get_vesting_locations/617b8bd8-6fdd-43eb-948a-4b17d1a0a089/
http://localhost:8000/vesting/617b8bd8-6fdd-43eb-948a-4b17d1a0a089/get_vesting_locations/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining the `action` with `detail=False` will tell the url that this view does not work on a single object. So it will build this url:

```
vesting/get_vesting_locations/
```

So trying to go to:

```
vesting/617b8bd8-6fdd-43eb-948a-4b17d1a0a089/get_vesting_locations/
```

will then give you a 404.

In order for this action to work with a single object and support the above url, set **`detail=True`**:

```
@action(detail=True, methods=['GET'], name='Get Vesting Locaitons')
def get_vesting_locations(self, request, pk=None, *args, **kwargs):
```